# How do I include 'pytz' package in my Django app for Heroku deployment?

Tags: django, heroku, pytz

I'm trying to include the pytz timezone package from (http://pytz.sourceforge.net/) into my Django app (version 1.3), so I can have improved time-zone functionality. I'm worried however that this python package won't be deployed onto my app in Heroku. How would I ensure that this package gets deployed on Heroku?

Or, if someone can tell me point me to ways to deal with TZ issues in Django 1.3, I'd highly appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the package to be deployed, add it to your `requirements.txt` file.

Comment: Oh, cool thanks. Could I just add "pytz==2012b" ? How do I get the package version?

Comment: For requirement file syntax, see the [docs](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/requirements.html). You can find out the version of packages you have installed by installing yolk `pip install yolk` and then executing it from your virtualenv `yolk -l`

Answer (score 6):

The package must be added to the requirement.txt file.

One way to determine the version number is to install things locally:

```
$ pip install pytz
$ python
>> import pytz
>> pytz.__version__
'2013b'
```

Then in requirements.txt append the following line:

```
pytz==2013b
```